# How to detect gesture on screen when phone is in sleep mode?

Tags: android

I want to create a Android app which will wake up the device when the user inputs a specific gesture on the screen of a phone that is in sleep mode. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. Only if the screen is one .  But maybe this article will help you...

[Getting touch events when screen is off article](https://nosemaj.org/android-persistent-sensors)

Comment: Thanks , will try it out